# Similarity between dimension of a vector space and order of a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

While studying groups, I've run into the following statement:

Let $f: G \to G'$ be a surjective homomorphism between groups with $K$ being the kernel of $f$. Then,
$$ |G| = |K|*|G'|. $$
This equation seems nearly identical to the dimension formula for vector spaces: namely, given a transformation between vector spaces $T: V \to W$,
$$ \text{dim }V = \text{dim}(\text{ker }T) + \text{dim}(\text{im }T).$$
These two equations seem extremely similar intuitively, but there's one main thing that confuses me. It seems to me that if you directly translated the statement about group order then the dimension of $V$ would be the product of the kernel and the image, not the sum. Is my confusion arising out of some misunderstanding of groups and vector spaces, or are the two equations unrelated? If they are related, could someone explain why in an intuitive manner?

Comment: If the vector spaces are over a finite field of order $q$, then a space of dimension $n$ has order $q^n$, so  multiplying the orders of two vector spaces corresponds to adding their dimensions.

Comment: It is as if you thought that multiplying a monomial of degree $m$ by a monomial of degree $n$, you obtain a monomial of degree $mn$.

Comment: You can indeed translate the statement for groups directly to the statement for vector spaces; you have
$$|V|=|\ker T|\ast|\operatorname{im} T|.$$
In fact this is just a special case of the first isomorphism theorem, because $V$ is an additive group, and $T$ is a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Multiplying* two exponentials with a common base is the same as *adding* their exponents: $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$. To make this an analogy, note that "size" is like $x^a$ whereas "dimension" is like $a$. This is super imprecise, but I imagine it gets the point across :)